# JavaScript set timeout loop return value

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have this function which pings my server for a specific change in data:

```
function connected() {
  $.ajax({
    success : function(d) {
      if (d.success) {
        // return data
      } else {
        setTimeout(connected, 200);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

(Obviously the code has been stripped to the bare minimum to make my intentions clearer)

What I want to do is return a bool true when it gets found, so I can go

```
if (connected()) {
  // process data
}
```

(obviously the data is stored in a global variable.)

Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT

I could create a 'pause' function:

```
function pauseScript(ms) {
  ms += new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < ms) {}
}
```

Then change my code to exclude setTimeout() (and include some other stuff)

```
function connected() {
  var value;
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    success : function(d) {
      if (d.success) {
        // set data
          value = true;
      } else {
        pauseScript(200);
        value = connected();
      }
    }
  });
  return value;
}
```

However this feels a little hacky!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Why can't I down-vote comments?

Comment: That's not the way to think about it! Nothing is impossible!

Comment: Don't try to pause using a while loop, you'll just lock the browser using 100% CPU (or the maximum browser can get) so may as well use a synchronous call.

Comment: Yeah, I did say it seemed hacky and I didn't even try it, I was just looking into pausing scripts,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing that the best should continue in async mode :

```
function connected(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    success : function(d) {
      if (d.success) {
        callback();
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          connected(callback);
        }, 200);
      }
    }
  });
}

//Using :
connected(function(){
  //Here i finish my scan result
});
```

Maybe, i'm not so sure in this case, you will need to bind this (I mean binding scope) :
http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/

Comment: The best part is, in my if statement I am calling another function so I can just put the function as the callback! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the browser you're targeting supports JavaScript 1.7 or later (At the time of writing, I think only Gecko browsers do) then you can utilize generators to do this. Let's first make your `connect` function asynchronous (and simpler for testing):

```
function connectAsync(callback) {
    // Pretend we always succeed after a second.
    // You could use some other asynchronous code instead.
    setTimeout(callback, 1000, true);
}
```

Now wrap your calling code into a function. (It must be in a function.)

```
function main() {
    console.log("Connecting...");
    if(!(yield connect())) {
        console.log("Failed to connect.");
        yield; return;
    }
    console.log("Connected.");
    yield;
}
```

Note all of the `yield`s everywhere. This is part of the magic. We need a `yield` when we call `connect` and a `yield` before every function exit point.

Now we need to define `connect`. You may have a bunch of asynchronous functions you may want to synchronize, so let's make a function that makes functions synchronous.

```
function synchronize(async) {
    return function synchronous() {
        return {func: async, args: arguments};
    };
}
```

And then we can create `connect` from `connectAsync` with it:

```
var connect = synchronize(connectAsync);
```

Now we need to make a function that runs all of this magic. Here it is:

```
function run(sync) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var runCallback = args.length ? args[args.length - 1] : null;
    if(args.length) {
        args.splice(args.length - 1, 1);
    }
    var generator = sync.apply(window, args);
    runInternal(generator.next());
    function runInternal(value) {
        if(typeof value === 'undefined') {
            if(runCallback) {
                return runCallback();
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
        function callback(result) {
            return runInternal(generator.send(result));
        }
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(value.args);
        args.push(callback);
        value.func.apply(window, args);
    }
}
```

Now you can run your `main` function with this magic:

```
run(main);
```

I should note that it is no longer possible for `main` to return a value. `run` can take a second argument: a callback to be called when the synchronous function has completed. To pass arguments to `main` (say, `1`, `2`, and `3`), you would call it like this:

```
run(main, 1, 2, 3, callback);
```

If you do not want a callback, pass `null` or `undefined`.

---

To try this out, you must set the `type` of the `script` tag to `text/javascript; version=1.7`. JavaScript 1.7 adds new keywords (like `yield`), so it is backwards-incompatible, and thus, must have some way to distinguish itself from older code.

For more information on generators, see [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). For more information on coroutines, see [the article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

**With all of that said, this is not practical** because of the limited support of JavaScript 1.7. Additionally, it is not common to see this sort of code, so it may be difficult to understand and maintain. **I would recommend just using an asynchronous style**, as demonstrated in [Deisss's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11286397). It is neat that it's *possible* to do this, however.

Comment: You summed it up yourself! Interesting but, at the current time, impractical. Great answer though!