# How to print a promise synchronously in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function returns a **Promise, which resolves to a random word string**. And I have a for loop go from 1 to 10. Each iteration, **if the number is multiple of 3, I need to print "Divided" otherwise print a random word**. The problem is **all the random numbers are printing at the end of the for loop, not in the order**. I tried with "`await`" but it says "await is only valid in async function". How can I do this task? (I need to keep getRandomWord function as it is)

```
const randomWords = require('random-words');

function getRandomWord() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(
            () => resolve(randomWords())
        );
    });
}

for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    if (i%3 === 0) {
        console.log(i + ": " + "divided" );
    }
    else {
        getRandomWord().then(result => {
            console.log(i + ": " + result);
        });
    }
}
```

**Output**

3: divided

6: divided

9: divided

11: chart

11: definition

11: suggest

11: stone

11: bet

11: circus

11: classroom

Comment: `(async function() { /* for loop with await here */ }())`. Note that doesn't make the promise synchronous. That's not possible. Instead it makes the `for` loop "wait" until the promise is resolved before it continues with the next iteration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set timeout loop return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286340/javascript-set-timeout-loop-return-value)

Comment: @RickardElimää I think my problem is slightly different. Because I have to keep set timeout here...

Comment: I accidently pressed return when selecting a duplicate. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop should be within an async function, and await the result of the call to `getRandomWord`

```
async function doWork()
{
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        if (i%3 === 0) {
            console.log(i + ": " + "divided" );
        }
        else {
            var result = await getRandomWord()
            console.log(i + ": " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Live example below.

```js
function getRandomWord() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(
            () => resolve("Hello, World")
        );
    });
}

async function doWork()
{
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        if (i%3 === 0) {
            console.log(i + ": " + "divided" );
        }
        else {
            var result = await getRandomWord()
            console.log(i + ": " + result);
        }
    }
}
doWork()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const test = async () => {
  for (let i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    if (i%3 === 0) {
        console.log(i + ": " + "divided" );
    } else {
        await getRandomWord().then(result => {
            console.log(i + ": " + result);
        });
    }
  }
}

test()
  .then(() => console.log('success'))
  .catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using [**`generators`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). I would recommend not to use `setTimeout` I can't find any purpose there to use `setTimeout`. It will unnecessarily add a callback to the `Event loop`.

This is the different approach that mentioned in the question, maybe it can help.

For providing clarity on how it works, I have added my own `randomWords` function. You can add your `randomWords` logic in that function.

```js
function *randomWords() {
var nextVal;

  while (true) {
    nextVal = parseInt(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    yield nextVal;
  }
}

let i = 1;

for (var v of randomWords()) {

  if(i%3 === 0){

    console.log(i + ": " + "divided" );
  }
  else{

         console.log(i + ": " + v);

  }

  // don't let the loop run forever!
  if (i > 10) {
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: That's a nicer way of creating the promise but it doesn't solve the OP's loop problem.

Comment: The loop problem is solved by using block scope `let`. I have used let in for loop.

Comment: That's a good catch too, but the OP's problem is that the `console.log`s are not in order. From the question: *"The problem is all the random numbers are printing at the end of the for loop, not in the order."*

Comment: @Felix Okay got it. Thanks I will update my answer for that.